# Display a transparent mov file on a webpage

Tags: html, flash, video, quicktime, alpha-transparency

I bought [this flying birds](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-video-11342270-pigeons-swoop.php?st=c2a7620) MOV file from istockphotos and now I'm stuck trying to implement it into my webpage, I want it to run like a flash file, every few seconds but I can't seem to be able to import it into Adobe Flash, I tried using the code below but it does not allow me to do much and is not transparent:

```
<OBJECT classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' width="320"
height="255" codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
  <param name='src' value="ad.mov">
  <param name='autoplay' value="true">
  <param name='controller' value="false">
  <param name='loop' value="false">
  <EMBED src="iStock_000011342270Small We.mov" width="320" height="255" autoplay="true" 
controller="false" loop="false" pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/'>
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

The person who created the stock wrote this on [his site](http://www.nickvdg.com/stock.html):

> Alpha Mattes and Luma Mattes
>
> Some of the clips contain alpha or luma mattes. If you don't know how
>   to use these, search online and discover their uses as masks. I've
>   heard from people who have converted my footage to use in Flash and
>   have successfully used the luma mattes there too. The black and white
>   clips of the birds can used as luma mattes, so the birds can be placed
>   on any background of your choice. As mentioned above, if you're using
>   After Effects, any of the clips can be used with the free Knoll
>   "UnMult" plugin which removes the black from the clips by creating an
>   alpha channel - it works really well with the rain and smoke clips.

I don't understand what a luma matte is, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There didn't seem to be a way to fix this issue, I ended up making the video transparent myself using Adobe After Effects and a great tutorial using Keying, it wasn't the best but it did the trick